# How to have one Unity DbContext per WF instance?

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework-5, unity-container, workflow-foundation-4

**Objective**: To have one DbContext instance per Workflow instance, for isolation of changes to prevent concurrency failures and to allow Transactions.

**Environment**: 
I use Unity in an N-tier (Services, Repository, EF5) application and re-use all the same interfaces/classes across the website and WF (Unity.WF, with custom Factory to add Unity RegisterTypes). I have the website's EF object running under the PerRequestLifetimeManager which works well, I'm trying to do the same for my WF instances.

I have one server running WF services (WF 4.5 with a WCF endpoint), soon this will need to be two (if that makes any difference to anyone's answers). I have multiple WF definitions (xamlx workflows), one in particular will soon be called 1000s of times a day to process files uploaded by clients. The processing time can be anywhere between <1 min to 1 hour depending on the amount of data uploaded, because of this is have set  to allow the incoming requests to persist immediately and then resume when the server is free.

**Problem**: 
The documented LifetimeManager for EF with Unity.WF is the HierarchicalLifetimeManager, but this seems to use the same EF instance across all running WF instances of the same WF definition.

I have tried several WCF Unity Lifetime Managers, but they all rely on the OperationContext.Current which is only available if the WF does not persist, this is not going to work for my situation.

So I tried the Microsoft WF Security Pack which claimed to be able to create/resurrect the OperationContext with an activity, this also does not work.

Surely this is a common problem that others have faced?

My next move would be to create my own LifetimeManager and *somehow* know about the workflow instance id and return the correct EF object from a Dictionary, but how would I get that id when the code is trying to resolve a dependency 2 levels deep in a repository constructor?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried a PerResolveLifetimeManager?

Comment: This has the same effect, it does not maintain the same DbContext across Activities in the same workflow, so transactions won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: 
Firstly, I could use a NativeActivity container and set the DataContext in the properties as in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tilovell/archive/2009/12/20/workflow-scopes-and-execution-properties.aspx. This does provide using the same DataContext for my child Activities.

My problem did not go away, it always failed in the same Activity, i suspect it is because of Lazy Loading. So, i finally used a lock in the Execute function to ensure that only 1 WF can run this activity at once with a volatile static bool to check against so that the other WFs can Delay and not block the maxConcurrentInstances.

I hope this helps someone else.